# Get leaf nodes for a specific tree in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table like below.

```
+------+----------------------+-----------+
|  Id  |       category       | parent_id |
+------+----------------------+-----------+
|    1 | ELECTRONICS          | NULL      |
|    2 | TELEVISIONS          | 1         |
|    3 | TUBE                 | 2         |
|    4 | LCD                  | 2         |
|    5 | PLASMA               | 2         |
|    6 | PORTABLE ELECTRONICS | 1         |
|    7 | MP3 PLAYERS          | 6         |
|    8 | FLASH                | 7         |
|    9 | CD PLAYERS           | 6         |
|   10 | 2 WAY RADIOS         | 6         |
|  100 | ELECTRONICS          | NULL      |
|  200 | TELEVISIONS          | 100       |
|  300 | TUBE                 | 200       |
|  400 | LCD                  | 200       |
|  500 | PLASMA               | 200       |
|  600 | PORTABLE ELECTRONICS | 100       |
|  700 | MP3 PLAYERS          | 600       |
|  800 | FLASH                | 700       |
|  900 | CD PLAYERS           | 600       |
| 1000 | 2 WAY RADIOS         | 600       |
+------+----------------------+-----------+
```

Where there are two trees stored as adjacency lists.Even if there are multiple trees I want to get leaf nodes for a single tree, given the root node.

I am following http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/ where we can get leaf node if an entire table is tree like.

```
SELECT t1.name FROM
category AS t1 LEFT JOIN category as t2
ON t1.category_id = t2.parent
WHERE t2.category_id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 2):

The adjacency list model has limitations,
and it's hard to select all leaf nodes for a specific subtree in mysql
without additional information...

In case you have additional information and know the height of subtree -
you can do something like this:

```
SELECT t2.name as name
FROM category AS t1
LEFT JOIN category AS t2 ON t2.parent = t1.category_id
LEFT JOIN category AS t3 ON t3.parent = t2.category_id
WHERE
    t1.name = 'TELEVISIONS' -- subtree
    AND t3.name IS NULL -- ensure it is leaf
;
```

But this is very restricted example and has many drawbacks:
you have to know height of subtree, subtree must be absolutely balanced, etc...

I'd rather advice you to use `The Nested Set Model`, in this case query will look

```
SELECT *
FROM nested_category AS node, nested_category AS parent
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt AND parent.name = 'TELEVISIONS'
AND node.rgt = node.lft + 1
;
```

moreover it'll work correctly for `PORTABLE ELECTRONICS`.